# Regular expression to stop at first match

Tags: regex

My regex pattern looks something like

```
<xxxx location="file path/level1/level2" xxxx some="xxx">
```

I am only interested in the part in quotes assigned to location. Shouldn't it be as easy as below without the greedy switch?

```
/.*location="(.*)".*/
```

Does not seem to work.

Comment: What's your source, is it HTML or xml or something?

Comment: Well, the source is an XML file, but I grep particular tags into a text file. For my purposes, this regex will probably suffice.

Answer (score 1604, accepted):

You need to make your regular expression lazy/non-greedy, because by default, `"(.*)"` will match all of `"file path/level1/level2" xxx some="xxx"`.

Instead you can make your dot-star non-greedy, which will make it match as few characters as possible:

```
/location="(.*?)"/
```

Adding a `?` on a quantifier (`?`, `*` or `+`) makes it non-greedy.

Note: this is only available in regex engines which implement the Perl 5 extensions (Java, Ruby, Python, etc) but not in "traditional" regex engines (including Awk, `sed`, `grep` without `-P`, etc.).

Comment: FWIW, incase your using VIM, this regex needs to be a little different: instead of `.*?` it's `.\{-}` for a non-greedy match.

Comment: Javascript *does* support _lazy quantifiers_.

Comment: how to emulate the non-greedy capture group for `awk`s without `gensub()` : `mawk 'sub("\42",___, $(_+=++_))+sub("^",__, $_)+gsub("^.*" __"|" ___".*$","")^(_-=_)' ___='\31\21' __='\37\27' FS=' location=\42'  ::::::::::::::: >>>>> 
file path/level1/level2`

Comment: 4 years of working with regex and this is probably the most useful thing I wish I knew earlier.

Comment: But the OP is only interested in the part in quotes assigned to location. This regex match location string as well. check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/9b24b22ce8c4). How can I get only the path?

Comment: Ah sorry. I switched the regex engine to PHP and now it works. here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ccf777e70a41)

Answer (score 92):

`location="(.*)"` will match from the `"` after `location=` until the `"` after `some="xxx` unless you make it non-greedy.

So you either need `.*?` (i.e. make it non-greedy by adding `?`) or better replace `.*` with `[^"]*`.

- `[^"]` Matches any character except for a " <quotation-mark>
- More generic: `[^abc]` - Matches any character except for an a, b or c

Comment: [^"]* is also probably faster with most regex engines because it does not need to lookup the pattern after the current pattern.

Comment: @Kip: You're probably right, but the `.*?` notation is more general than `[^"]*`

Comment: how about if I want to include the delimiter character using [^"]*

Comment: not at all, if you don't know what ^ and [ ] mean here. Most people will understand .*

Comment: Another benefit of this approach is that it supports matching over line-breaks which the the dot "." does not support unless PCRE_DOTALL / DOT_MATCH_ALL or similar flags/modifiers.

Answer (score 47):

How about

```
.*location="([^"]*)".*
```

This avoids the unlimited search with .* and will match exactly to the first quote.

Comment: Due to [discrepancies in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454172/non-greedy-matching-with-grep) the above should be the preferred pattern if portability is a concern.

Answer (score 38):

Use non-greedy matching, if your engine supports it. Add the ? inside the capture.

```
/location="(.*?)"/
```

Answer (score 22):

Use of Lazy quantifiers `?` with no global flag is the answer.

Eg,

[image]

If you had global flag `/g` then, it would have matched all the lowest length matches as below. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here fail to spell out a full solution for regex versions which don't support non-greedy matching. The greedy quantifiers (`.*?`, `.+?` etc) are a Perl 5 extension which isn't supported in traditional regular expressions.

If your stopping condition is a single character, the solution is easy; instead of

```
a(.*?)b
```

you can match

```
a[^ab]*b
```

i.e specify a character class which excludes the starting and ending delimiiters.

In the more general case, you can *painstakingly* construct an expression like

```
start(|[^e]|e(|[^n]|n(|[^d])))end
```

to capture a match between `start` and the first occurrence of `end`. Notice how the subexpression with nested parentheses spells out a number of alternatives which between them allow `e` only if it isn't followed  by `nd` and so forth, and also take care to cover the empty string as one alternative which doesn't match whatever is disallowed at that particular point.

Of course, the correct approach in most cases is to use a proper parser for the format you are trying to parse, but sometimes, maybe one isn't available, or maybe the specialized tool you are using is insisting on a regular expression and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way.

Here's the one you want. This is lazy `[\s\S]*?`

**The first item:**
`[\s\S]*?(?:location="[^"]*")[\s\S]*` Replace with: `$1`

**Explaination**: https://regex101.com/r/ZcqcUm/2

---

For completeness, this gets the last one. This is greedy `[\s\S]*`

**The last item:**`[\s\S]*(?:location="([^"]*)")[\s\S]*` 
Replace with: `$1`

**Explaination**: https://regex101.com/r/LXSPDp/3

---

There's only 1 difference between these two regular expressions and that is the `?`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using *quantified subpattern* and as descried in [Perl Doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions),

> By default, a quantified subpattern is "**greedy**", that is, it will
>   match as **many times** as possible (given a particular starting location)
>   while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match. If you want it
>   **to match the minimum number of times** possible, follow the quantifier
>   **with** a "?" . Note that the meanings don't change, just the
>   "greediness":

```
*?        //Match 0 or more times, not greedily (minimum matches)
+?        //Match 1 or more times, not greedily
```

Thus, to allow your *quantified* pattern to make minimum match, follow it by `?` :

```
/location="(.*?)"/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import regex
text = 'ask her to call Mary back when she comes back'                           
p = r'(?i)(?s)call(.*?)back'
for match in regex.finditer(p, str(text)):
    print (match.group(1))
```

Output:
Mary

Answer (score 0):

perhaps keep it simple ?

```
printf '%s' '<xxxx location="file path/level1/level2" xxxx some="xxx">' | 

{m,g,n}awk NF++ FS='^(.+ )?location="|".*$' OFS=
```

> 

```
file path/level1/level2
```