# Match just once with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this regex to mach some words without numbers and it works well

```
(?:searchForThis|\G).+?(\b[^\d\s]+?\b)
```

The problem that Regex searching the entire document and not only in the line that contains searchForThis

So if I have 2 times searchForThis it will take them twice

I want to stop it only on that 1st line so it will not search the other lines after
Any help please?

I'm using Regex with php

Example of the problem here: http://www.rubular.com/r/vPhk8VbqZR

In the example you will see :

```
Match 1
1.  word
Match 2
1.  worldtwo
Match 3
1.  wordfive
Match 4
1.  word
Match 5
1.  worldtwo
Match 6
1.  wordfive
```

But I need only :

```
Match 1
1.  word
Match 2
1.  worldtwo
Match 3
1.  wordfive
```

You will see that it's doing twice

===========Edit for more details as asked ===========================

In my php I have :

```
define('CODE_REGEX', '/(?:searchForThis|\G(?<!^)).*?(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)/iu')
```

Output :

```
if (preg_match_all(CODE_REGEX, $content, $result))
            return trim($result[1][0].' '.$result[1][1].' '.$result[1][2].' '.$result[1][3].' '.$result[1][4].' '.$result[1][5]);
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you're looking for this:

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match

Comment: Hello Federik not sure to well understand your suggestion

Comment: It works well with preg_match_all

Comment: use preg_match instead? :)

Comment: If I use preg_much it doesn't what I want
It's capturing names without numbers 
Just I want that it searched on the first line found and not going ahead for the hole document

Comment: @amorino: Rather than rubular link provide your input and expected match in the question itself.

Comment: @anubhava ok I will edit my question right now

Comment: No idea dear friends ?

Comment: @amorino: What is value of `$content`?

Comment: @anubhava I'm using cakePhp as this :

`public static function getDoctorName($content) {
  if (PROVIDER == '1') {
   if (preg_match(CodeA_REGEX, $content, $result))
   return trim($result[0]);
  } else if (PROVIDER == '2') {

   if (preg_match_all(CODE_REGEX, $content, $result))
   return trim($result[1][0].' '.$result[1][1].' '.$result[1][2].' '.$result[1][3].' '.$result[1][4].' '.$result[1][5]);
   
  
  }
  return null;
 }`

Comment: @amorino: Not the code I was asking that does string `$content` hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern instead:

```
(?:\A[\s\S]*?searchForThis|\G).*?(\b[a-z]+\b)/iu
```

or

```
(?:\A(?s).*?searchForThis|\G)(?-s).*?(\b[a-z]+\b)/iu
```

To deal with multiple line between the first "searchForThis" and others or the end of the string, you can use this: (with your example string you will obtain "After" and "this".)

```
(?:\A.*?searchForThis|\G)(?>[^a-z]++|\b[a-z]++\S)*?(?!searchForThis)(\b[a-z]+\b)/ius
```

Note: in all the three pattern you can replace `\A` with `^` since the multiline mode is not used. Be carefull with rubular that is designed for ruby regexes: m in ruby = s in php (that is the dotall/singleline mode), m in php is the multiline mode (each start of the line can be matched with `^`)

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuu a lot 
I was searching for this for 7 days and nights 
Thank you thank you 
Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: Great regex, but it won't work if we've got another useless line before.

Comment: \A[\s\S]*? tell to search only on that line?

Comment: No, it means `Start of the input string, followed by any char, x time`. Note `\A` differs from `^` as it match the start of the **input string**, not the **line**.

Comment: @zessx: Yes however, you can use `^` instead, since the multiline mode is not set, it has the same meaning.

Comment: Interesting... @amorino You can use `(?s:^.*?searchForThis|\G).*?(?<words>\b[a-z]+\b)/iu` to get all words in `$results['words']`

Comment: @Casmir et Hippolyte and @zessx
Thank you a lot for all that precious help
The solution 1 worked like a charm the 2 and 3 no
I added the suggestion of zessx so :
`(?:\A[\s\S]*?searchForThis|\G).*?(?<words>\b[a-z]+\b)/iu`
and 
`$results['words']`
You saved my life ;)

Comment: @amorino: Test 2 and 3 directly in php, or with http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com . Rubular is for Ruby

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte directly in php and in the rubular site

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in two stages :

```
// get the first line with 'searchForThis'
preg_match('/searchForThis(?<line>.*)\n/m', $text, $results);
$line = $results['line'];

// get every word from this line
preg_match_all('/\b[a-z]+\b/i', $line, $results);
$words = $results[0];
```

Another way, based on the great Casimir's answer (just for readibility) :

```
preg_match_all('/(?s:^.*?searchForThis|\G).*?(?<words>\b[a-z]+\b)/iu', $str, $results);
$words = $results['words'];
```