# Matching first occurrence?

Tags: regex

I know this question has been asked many times, but when I attempted to use the accepted answer that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match), it does not work, so I assume I'm missing something.

I was attempting to match the `Mrs.` in the string `Rothschild, Mrs. Martin (Elizabeth L. Barrett)` using this regular express:

```
.*, (.*\.).*
```

But this does not work because of the `L.`.  I then attempted to add the `?` a number of different ways, but it still matches all the way to `L.`.  Some things I tried:

```
.*, (.*\.?).*
.*, (.*\.*?).*
.*, (.*\.+?).*
.*, (.*\.??).*
```

But none of these work.  Can anyone see what I am missing here?

[Regex Fiddle](http://www.regexr.com/39i9f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `?` after the `*` which was present inside the capturing group. `.*` is greedy and eats up characters as many as possible. You need to add a quantifier `?` after the `*` to do a shortest possible match.

```
.*, (.*?\.).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iQ2hK3/4)

Comment: Yes! There it is!  Thanks, will accept in 11 minutes