# Print only the first occurrence in a matcher

Tags: java, regex

I use the following code to extract the age of a user in one document, but his age appears several times:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})(?=-year-old)");
Matcher matcher = r.matcher("He is a 55-year-old doctor. xxxxx. As a 55-year-old man he xxxx. When he is 55-year-old , xxxx");
if(matcher.find()) {    
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
                }
```

Finally I get the result:

```
55
55
55
```

How can I just print `55` once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code as it is prints `55` only once. Is that not what you want??

Comment: @abishek, he only wants the first instance.

Comment: Show us the whole loop you use you use.

Comment: I should mention that "xxx" in the text also contains other numbers.

Comment: @Basilevs Actually, you can consider there is no loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make it non-greedy by adding **?**

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})(?=-year-old)?");
```

should work, [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match) for detail

Comment: `"(\\d{2})(?=-year-old)?"` means there is no use in the lookahead, and you suggest `\d{2}`. However, OP code works anyway.