# How can I get my Regular Expression to take the first match, and ignore any following matches?

Tags: regex, rubular

I am making regular expressions to extract dosage instructions from a pharmaceutical catalog. I am getting information from many different brands, and formatting is not consistent even within a brand so my expression has to be kind of lenient. The regular expressions are being implemented in Ruby (but not by me).

My regex is as follows:

```
/(take|chew\s|usage:|use:|intake:|dosage:?|dose:|directions:|recommendations:|adults:)\s*(.*take\s+|.*chew\s+|.*mix\s+|.*supplement,\s+)?(?<dosage_amount>\S+(\sto\s\S+)?(\sor\s\S+)?(\s\(\d+\)\s)?\b)[\s,](?<dosage_format>\S+\b(\s\([\w\-\.]+\))?)?[\s,]*?(?<dosage_frequency>[\S\s]*(daily|per day|a day|needed|morning|evening))?[\s,]?\s?(daily\s)?(?<dosage_permutation>(with|on|at|in|before|after|taken)[,\w\s\-]*)?(?=or as|\.)?/
```

An example of the code working correctly would be with the following description --

"**Suggested use: As a dietary supplement, take 1-3 capsules daily,in divided doses, before a meal.**"

-- where I get **dosage_amount= 1-3**, **dosage_format= capsule**, **dosage_frequency= once per day**, and **dosage_permutation= "in divided doses, before a meal"**.

However, I am getting problems with descriptions like:

"**Directions: 
For adults, take one (1) tablet daily, preferably with a meal or follow the advice of your health care professional. Let tablets dissolve on tongue before swallowing. As a reminder, discuss the supplements and medications you take with your health care providers.** "

The problem is where the word "take" is used more than once in the description. I will get **dosage_amount= with**, and **dosage_format= your**. (It is matching the second 'take', and not the first.)

Is there a way to force regex to only match the first 'take' in the description? I have tried experimenting with making it greedy vs. non-greedy as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match?rq=1), but I can not make it work.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us your attempt to make it non-greedy, because I think that should do it. We need to see what you tried so we can help you understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Sleafar's answer worked - I'd tried to make the 'take' itself non-greedy instead of the characters before it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the greedy part here:

```
.*take
```

with a non greedy version:

```
.*?take
```

The first variant consumes as many characters as possible, the second as few as possible.