# Return first occurrence of Regex not matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a code like this https://jsfiddle.net/tgvtceg3/

```js
var text = "abc(de192/+£,€.&";
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\,+&.\/]+$/);
var res = pattern.test(text)
alert(res);
```

I want that code return first occurrence not matched in regex... for example in thi case I want "("

Any suggest are welcome

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Please give more information on the result you're expecting and why this does not work for you

Comment: right... I have edited my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to stop at first match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Comment: It is not that dupe. This question is not about matching up to the leftmost occurrence of a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use another regex to check the text that made your previous validation regex fail to match. Use something like this:

```js
var text = "abc(de192/+£,€.&";
var pattern = /^[0-9a-zA-Z,+&.\/-]+$/;
var res = pattern.test(text)
if (!res) {
   var m=text.match(/[^0-9a-zA-Z,+&.\/-]+/) || [""];
   console.log(m[0]);
}
```

The `/[^0-9a-zA-Z,+&.\/-]+/` regex will find the first occurrence of the char other than those defined in your original regex.

**EDIT**: Using a dynamic approach to pattern building:

```js
var text = "abc(de192/+£,€.&";
var block = "0-9a-zA-Z,+&./-"; // Define ranges/chars here
var pattern = new RegExp("^[" + block + "]+$"); // Use constructor notation to build the validation regex
var res = pattern.test(text)
if (!res) {
   var m=text.match(new RegExp("[^" + block + "]+")) || [""];
   console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks...  Do you know how I can change dinamically from this /^[0-9a-zA-Z,+&.\/-]+$/ to this /[^0-9a-zA-Z,+&.\/-]+/... replace?

Comment: See my edit showing how to build the patterns dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a negative regex to define and then just use `string.match(regex)` to get all matches.

To get first mismatch, just do `result[0]`

Regex: `/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\,+&.\/]/g`

This will match all characters except mentioned ones.

```js
var text = "abc(de192/+£,€.&";
var pattern = new RegExp(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\,+&.\/]/g);
var res = text.match(pattern)
console.log(res);
console.log(res[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

> You need to make your regular expression non-greedy, because by
>   default, "(.*)" will match all of "file path/level1/level2" xxx
>   some="xxx".

So I hope this will help, by adding '?' to the end of your regex to make it nongreedy, and move the ^ to the character section in the regex.
for debug regex, I use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) which is great.

```js
var text = "abc(de192/+£,€.&";
var pattern = new RegExp(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\,+&.\/]?/);
var res = pattern.test(text)
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `^` into the beginning of the character case to look for any character not inside it:

```js
var text = "abc(de192/+£,€.&";
var pattern = new RegExp(/([^0-9a-zA-Z\-\,+&.\/]+)/);
var res = pattern.exec(text);
console.log(res ? res[0] : undefined);
```

Comment: Sorry but please check other answers as this has been covered in more than 1 answer.

Comment: @Rajesh This answer also briefly explains the logic as well as handles a case where `res` has no matches (besides for using `exec` instead and omitting the `g` modifier which isn't needed). BTW I wrote this before seeing your answer.