# How to put style to particular digits from numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

```
[$number=$row['plate_number'];//it will have many numbers ex:78666,78686,78006

ex:$number="78666";  // random sample

in this ex:first 786 digit in red color and remaining 66 in normal color(78666)

ex1:$number="78006";  // random sample
```

in this ex1:
we to color 786 to red, 78 digits red and followed by 00 normal color and 6 should be red(78006)

Here a link to what I want:
[image]

Comment: What have your tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: To go with what @Oliver said, what is your required output (Excel,  HTML, etc)? What are all the rules associated with coloring of output?

Comment: In your question you want 786 in red and the remaining 66 in normal color. Yet in the picture, the number 78666 is completely red.

Comment: $find=array("786");
        $replace=array("<span style='color:red;'>786</span>");
        $string1=str_replace($find,$replace,$row['plate_number']);  i have tried this here only it will color only 786.... but i need other occurence as well which in image

Comment: tht was little mistake in image

Comment: @Shakif Again, what *rules*. Is it just the first 6, you want digits > 0, why make 1 number red and **not** the other one?

Comment: it should follow from 786...... in some case numbers will be 78006...here i wanna put red color to 786...... in some case number will be 78600 here i wanna put red color to 786  remaining normal color

Comment: more possibilities will come ..... we should follow first 7 followed by 8 followed by 6 should be red (some case in between any other digits will come that we have to put as normal color)

Comment: So you want to match the first 3 characters of the string to be `786`, turn that to red and not doing anything with the other ones?

Comment: @Xorifelse No he wants `78006` to have 7,8 and 6 to be red too. He wants those numbers red if they are in the specific order 1=7, 2=8 ,3=6 and only the first oocurences of those number apparently.

Comment: yeah, first 3 but some times 78006 will come in this case we have to put red color to 786 in between 00 will normal color

Comment: yes your right bro @Xorifelse

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: @Shakif What should be the outcome when the number is: `87686` ?

Comment: 87686  in this 2nd digit 7 and last two digits 86 should red color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve that is to use a regex, as such :

```
$string = preg_replace('#([0-9]*?)(7)([0-9]*?)(8)([0-9]*?)(6)([0-9]*?)#', '$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>$3<span style="color: red;">$4</span>$5<span style="color: red;">$6</span>$7', $string);
```

This regex will match :

1. `([0-9]*?)` : zero or more numeric characters, not replacing them
2. `(7)` : the first occurence of `7`, replacing it with `<span style="color: red;">7</span>`
3. `([0-9]*?)` : zero or more numeric characters, not replacing them
4. `(8)` : the first occurence of `8`, replacing it with `<span style="color: red;">8</span>`
5. `([0-9]*?)` : zero or more numeric characters, not replacing them
6. `(6)` : the first occurence of `6`, replacing it with `<span style="color: red;">6</span>`
7. `([0-9]*?)` : zero or more numeric characters, not replacing them

If `7`, `8` and `6` are not found in the string in that order, this will do nothing.

**EDIT :** Added `?` for each `[0-9]*` in order to make the quantifier ungreedy (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503438))

Comment: `78606` returns with the last 6 in red and not the other one.

Comment: @Shakif So `78606` with this code works the way you want to?

Comment: I think you just accidentally added the `'$1<span style="color: red;">$2</span>$3<span style="color: red;">$4</span>$5<span style="color: red;">$6</span>$7'` twice in the regex

Comment: Indeed I did. Damn you, copy/paste.