# In string column, remove text preceding first comma (delimiter)

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, gsub

This has to be a simple sub or gsub but I can't seem to find it on soverflow. Likely a duplicate someplace, but somewhere I can't seem to find.

data

```
df <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4),c2=c("431, Dallas, TX", "c63728 , Denver, CO", ",New Orleans, LA", "somewhere,NY, NY"))
```

data desired

```
df.desired <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4),c2=c("Dallas, TX", "Denver, CO", "New Orleans, LA", "NY, NY"))
```

**Edited for the good answer below by pasqui for what I asked, but I'm modifying the question slightly**

I'd just like to remove the first string and comma. So I'd like it to work in below as well:

data

```
df <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4),c2=c("431, Dallas, TX, 75225", "c63728 , Denver, CO, 80121", ",New Orleans, LA", "somewhere,NY, NY"))
```

data desired

```
df.desired <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4),c2=c("Dallas, TX, 75225", "Denver, CO, 80121", "New Orleans, LA", "NY, NY"))
```

Comment: [`stringi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/stringi.pdf) package probably does what you want too, it's very full-featured and vectorized. I wasn't able to figure out at first glance

Comment: Are you guaranteed there are exactly two commas, or at least two commas? R has no right-split that I can find, so you need regex as people showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R you can use:

```
df$desired  <- trimws(gsub(pattern='^.*?,', replacement = '', df$c2), which='left')
```

Or with the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(desired = 
           str_replace(c2, pattern = '^.*?,', replacement = ""),
         desired = str_trim(desired, side='left')) -> df
```

The '^.*?,' expression looks for any values at the start of the string up to the first comma. The ? makes the expression non-greedy when searching for a comma as per this answer on stack overflow:

[Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(c2 = gsub("(^.*,\\s{0,1})(.*,.*$)", "\\2", c2))

#Output
  c1              c2
1  1      Dallas, TX
2  2      Denver, CO
3  3 New Orleans, LA
4  4          NY, NY
```

NB: This is a solution based on "capturing groups": they are good in terms of cognitive economy (for the human). The are more efficient options for the machine.

## Editing:

### Tweaking the regex to cope with both cases

I keep playing with Regex Capturing groups

Given the second data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4),c2=c("431, Dallas, TX, 75225", "c63728 , Denver, CO, 80121", ",New Orleans, LA", "somewhere,NY, NY"))
```

We apply:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(c2 = gsub("(^.*,{1}?)(.*,.*$)", "\\2", c2))
```

And the output is:

```
  c1                 c2
1  1  Dallas, TX, 75225
2  2  Denver, CO, 80121
3  3    New Orleans, LA
4  4             NY, NY
```

It works for your first example as well

Comment: This works great for my example, but any idea if there are more than two groups i.e. c19183, Denver, CO, 80121 and I just want to keep all three after the first comma? I.e. there I'd want (Denver, CO, 80121), see the above question edits.

Comment: @NealBarsch I just saw your comment and edit; thus, I tweaked my regex accordingly. `Capturing Groups` are even more flexible than that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_split`, remove the first entry of each vector and then paste them all back together

```
df %>% 
  mutate(c2 = c2 %>% str_split(",") %>%
           lapply(function(x){
             x[-1] %>% 
               str_trim() %>% 
               str_c(collapse = ", ")
           }))
```