# python regular expressions, return only first match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to return only first match from bellow variable

```
MACHINE: p1prog06<br>

MACHINE: p1prog06
```

using following expression:

```
res = list(set([re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|[\r\n]+', '', m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)', email_body, re.M)]))
```

According to documentations,

```
`list(set(res))`
```

should return unique values, but i'm getting

```
u'p1prog06', u'p1prog06<br><br>']
```

Code:

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
conn.login(user,pwd)
conn.select("test")

resp, items = conn.uid("search" ,None, '(OR (FROM "email@pexample.com) (FROM "email2@pexample.com"))')



items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
    if resp == 'OK':
        email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
        #get all emails with words "PA1" or "PA2" in subject
        if mail["Subject"].find("PA1") > 0 or mail["Subject"].find("PA2") > 0:
                  #search email body for job name (string after word "JOB")
          regex1 = r'(?<!^)JOB:\s*(\S+)'
          #regex2 = r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:\s*^\d+)?)'
          #c=re.searchall(regex2, email_body, re.M)#,re.DOTALL)
          a=re.findall(regex1 ,email_body)
          #res = [re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|[\r\n]+', '', m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)', email_body, re.M)]
          res = list(set([re.sub(r'=(?:\^M\<br><br>)?|[\r\n]+', '', m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)', email_body, re.M)]))
```

Comment: Those two values are obviously not the same, and therefore they *are* unique. Note: *"unique"* does not mean *"only one"*. It just means "*no repetitions*".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match

Comment: You might also remove all `<br>` tags, `re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|<br\s*(?:/\s*)?>|[\r\n]+', '', m.group(1))`, and `list(set())` will do its job. FYI: The `re.M` is no longer necessary, there are no anchors in the pattern.

Comment: thanks again Wikor, you saved me again, it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main regex used in `re.finditer` matches `<br>` tags. All you need is to remove them with the `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|<br\s*(?:/\s*)?>|[\r\n]+', '', m.group(1))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You may also use it with `re.findall` like this:

```
res = list(set([re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|<br\s*(?:/\s*)?>|[\r\n]+', '', m) for m in re.findall(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)', email_body)]))
```

Note `re.M` is redundant and is removed.

The `<br\s*(?:/\s*)?>` pattern matches `<br`, then `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces, `(?:/\s*)?` matches an opptional sequence of `/` and 0+ whitespaces, and `>` finally matches `>`. So, it can match `<br/>`, `<br>`, `<br />` and even `<br / >`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment points out, your examples are not unique so the functionality seems correct. Either add a term to the `sub` method to remove the `<br>` tags (and then your set command will drop the duplicate entries). Or if you only want the first match from the `email_body` maybe try just use the `search` method in the regex package.

Comment: Why not include some code to elaborate your point? Also `<br>` is not a tag here it is just the part of the string and `set` is not a command it is a class which convert the values into hashes and when two values generate same hash value that is how we get the unique values and that is the reason they are unordered.

Comment: thanks for answer, i tried `re.sub(r'=(?:\^M\<br><br>)?|[\r\n]+` but nothing changed

Comment: I believe what you have suggested above tries to match the `<br><br>` directly after the M. The following should work: `re.sub(r'(M.*:)|(\s)+|(<br>)', ...)`. But I prefer @Predicate's answer so up-voting that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can improve your regex to [this](https://regex101.com/r/tQjwV7/1/):

```
\bMACHINE:\s*([^<]*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)
```

Now youre regex will stop at the `<` sign.