# Problems matching '\n' in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm practicing PowerShell on Codewars. I'm currently struggling with [this rather easy exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56baeae7022c16dd7400086e/train/powershell).

My problem is that my match is not matching correctly or I haven't understood what kind of string the Input is. I'm trying find the data set to a given number.
The input is a string, representing a phonebook. The information in each set is in a random order.

So I already tried to first split the input after every new line (`-split "\n"`). Didn't work, so I tried it with match. (e.g. `-match ".*48-421-674-8974.*\n"`).
Now what I would expect in `Matches`, is all information to that number until the next '\n'. But instead I'm getting the data set I wanted PLUS the next line. I've already tried `\\n`, `\\\\n`, single/double quotes. But I can't find any solution by myself.

So currently my input is this:

```
"<Sophia Loren> +1-421-674-8974 Bern TP-46017\n <Peter O'Brien> High  
Street +1-908-512-2222; CC-47209\n"*
"<Anastasia> +48-421-674-8974 Via Quirinal Roma\n <P Salinger> 
Main  Street, +1-098-512-2222, Denver\n"*
"<C Powel> *+19-421-674-8974 Chateau des Fosses Strasbourg F-68000\n 
<Bernard >Deltheil +1-498-512-2222; Mount Av.  Eldorado\n"
```

And my regex `".*48-421-674-8974.*\\n"`

[(My Regex online)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*48-421-674-8974.*%5c%5cn&i=%22%3cSophia+Loren%3e+%2b1-421-674-8974+Bern+TP-46017%5cn+%3cPeter+O%27Brien%3e+High+Street+%2b1-908-512-2222%3b+CC-47209%5cn%22*%0d%0a%22%3cAnastasia%3e+%2b48-421-674-8974+Via+Quirinal+Roma%5cn+%3cP+Salinger%3e+Main+Street%2c+%2b1-098-512-2222%2c+Denver%5cn%22*%0d%0a%22%3cC+Powel%3e+*%2b19-421-674-8974+Chateau+des+Fosses+Strasbourg+F-68000%5cn+%3cBernard+Deltheil%3e+%2b1-498-512-2222%3b+Mount+Av.++Eldorado%5cn%22*%0d%0a)

I'd expect this result:

```
<Anastasia> +48-421-674-8974 Via Quirinal Roma\n
```

but I'm getting:

```
"<Anastasia> +48-421-674-8974 Via Quirinal Roma\n <P Salinger> Main Street, +1-098-512-2222, Denver\n"
```

I've also tried matching or spliting again after this result, but that did'nt work either.

Comment: In a PS string, a newline is defined as ``"`n"`` and backslashes are treated as literal chars.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change anything in the result :/

Comment: I think that's what you've specified. Your .* matches all characters until the last occurence of \n.

Comment: What result? Provide a reproducible example if you need real help, not just hints. It is not totally clear if you have newlines or two-char combinations of ``\`` and `n`. It is not clear how you get the data, from a file or some variable.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I guess that's the right hint. How do I match until the first occurence of \n?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is a greedy match. What you want is a non-greedy match (`.*?`) starting with an opening angular bracket, including the phone number, and ending with a literal backslash and the character "n".

```cs
$inputText = @'
"<Sophia Loren> +1-421-674-8974 Bern TP-46017\n <Peter O'Brien> High Street +1-908-512-2222; CC-47209\n"*
"<Anastasia> +48-421-674-8974 Via Quirinal Roma\n <P Salinger> Main  Street, +1-098-512-2222, Denver\n"*
"<C Powel> *+19-421-674-8974 Chateau des Fosses Strasbourg F-68000\n <Bernard >Deltheil +1-498-512-2222; Mount Av. Eldorado\n"
'@

$pattern = '<.*?48-421-674-8974.*?\\n'

$inputText |
    Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I have imported your input text (keeping the \n characters intact) and wrote this line that does the `regex` matching:

```
([regex]".*48-421-674-8974[a-zA-Z ]+\\n").Matches($text)
```

Now it might happen that if you load the actual phone address data from a file, the newline character might need to be specified like Wiktor Stribizew said as a `` "`n" ``

Comment: Please don't use citation formatting  (`> `) for code snippets.