# How do you use "repeat ... until" in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have the following list:

```
find **data** find find
find **data** find find
find **data** find find
find **data** find find
found
find data find find
find data find find
```

I would like to match all `**data**` until the word "found". All **data** after `found` I would like to escape.

Comment: are you using script/ programs or you want to active that from cli

Comment: In what programming language and what regex engine?

Comment: Please use the [edit] feature to edit your original question, rather than posting additional details of the question as an answer.  This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Comment: Please add the tag of the tool/language to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead to assert that `found` appears somewhere after the match:

```
(?s)\*\*data\*\*(?=.*found)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/EoDFM5uknzz0wu).

If your language/tool does not support the DOTALL flag `(?s)`, use flag options (often `m`), eg

```
/\*\*data\*\*(?=.*found)/m
```