# python regular expression pattern to get digits in between_

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-re

I want to find regular expression pattern to match digits between XYZ_  and first underscore.

```
Example want to get 2M284904C4 from below string.

 XYZ_2M284904C4_20210201_120032.xyz
```

I tried `XYZ_.*_`,but it matches `XYZ_2M284904C4_20210201_`

Comment: `2M284904C4` isn't all digits.

Comment: You can use `[^_]*` to match a sequence of characters that are *not* an underscore.

Comment: this is called "greedy matching"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Answer (score 1):

Try string.split() at the underscores, and then select the item you want from the returned list. For example,

```
string = 'XYZ_2M284904C4_20210201_120032.xyz'
string_list = string.split('_')
result = string_list[1]
```