# Extract a part of a string using Regex in Python Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-science, extract

I'm a student working on a data science project and I need to extract a part from one column of my dataframe.
The dataframe looks like this :
[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSx2V.png).

I want to extract the part HOTHOTVIDEO from a string like "HOTHOTVIDEO**HOT0501005107**FilmVidéoClub"

So I wrote this instruction using a regex like this :
`facturation['annotation']=facturation['annotation'].str.findall('([A-Z0-9]{3}\d+)').apply(''.join)`

It extracts everything correclty, except sometimes when I have strings like these : "CTVCANALVODCTV0200052670CTV0200052670", it returns **CTV0200052670CTV0200052670**, but only want the first occurence: [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUSs9.png)

Can someone help me to fix this issue please :)

Comment: There was a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Comment: It’s not related, though, @okpython . The reason for that problem is the regex pattern itself. The reason for this one is the work done  on that pattern.

Comment: Why do you use `findall` then? Use `extract`, `.str.extract(r'([A-Z0-9]{3}\d+)')`

Comment: I already tried using `extract`, It fixes the problem but it leads to a another problem. That is it can only extract **MFE05** from the strings like MFEMETROPOLITAN**MFE05**UH622455AlaskaHD. That's why I used ```findall``` cuz it returns all the matches. :(

Comment: What about `str.extract(r'([A-Z]{1,3}\d{3,})')`? Or `str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2,3}\d{3,})')`?

Comment: Please clarify your requirements to make the question answerable.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I found the answer to my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks everyone who helped me :) I found the answer :

`facturation['annotation'] = facturation['annotation'].str.findall('([A-Z0-9]{3}\d+)').apply(''.join)`

`facturation['annotation'] = facturation['annotation'].str.extract('(.{0,13})')`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your *apply + join* and *findall* methods, because you have matched 2 times this pattern in your data and next you have joined it. *findall* returns for you list. From the list you need only 1st item, not all.