# Regex find url with specefic character inside (js)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

```
Some text
{\"url\": \"https:\/\/www.someurl.com\/200x200\/fsdffsde3e", \"bbb\"} kljkl
{\"url\": \"https:\/\/www.someurl.com\/500x500\/fsdffsde3e", \"bbb\"} kljkl
Some text
```

I want to extract all the URLs contains `200x200`. so for example I need this URL: `https:\/\/www.someurl.com\/200x200\/fsdffsde3e`

this, will bring the entire row: `"https(.*?)200x200(.*)"`  but I want only the URL.
Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/DDWLDM/1

Thanks

Comment: Use `.*?` everywhere, or `[^"]*` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14997763/3832970)).

Answer (score 0):

use This exp

```
"https(.*?)200x200(.*?)"
```

Comment: Brings only part of the url