# Regex different hashes

Tags: grep

so I'm struggling with regex. I'll start with what I want to achieve and then proceed to what I have "so far".

So for example I have commit name lines

```
merge(#2137): done something
Merge pull request #420 from Example/branch
feat(): done something [#2137JDN]
merge(#690): feat(): done something [#2137JDN]
```

And I want to grep only by PR ID, or if it's not there then it'd search by that second hash

```
#2137
#420
#2137JDN
#690
```

For now I have this regex, but it's not perfect

```
/(\(|\s|\[)(#\d+|#.+)(\)|\s|\])/g
```

because it's capturing this

```
(#2137)
\s#420\s
[#2137JDN]
(#690)[#2137JDN]
```

How I can improve it to get what I want exactly?

Comment: Are you using `re` package in python?

Comment: What about `(?<=[(\s[])#[^\])\s]+`? See https://regex101.com/r/w9UxHj/1

Comment: @MohammadRifatArefin for now I didn't decide in which language I want to write down the script. For now I'm testing solution of regex on https://regexr.com/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hmm, it's using positive lookbehind and it's a little bit more complicated than answer below, but yes it's working.

Comment: But it can be just [`#\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/w9UxHj/2), too. It depends on the logic you actually need to implement.

Comment: Yes it is, but it does not validate the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `#[\dA-Z]+` pattern to grep only hashes.

```
command | grep -Po "#[\dA-Z]+"
```

Which returns the all matched strings (in our case - hashes)

```
#2137
#420
#2137JDN
#690
#2137JDN
```

Unfortunately, `grep` does not support `non-greedy` feature. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match#answer-2503438) answer.

Comment: Oh thanks! I mean I didn't decided yet in which script language (or tool like `grep`) I'll use it, I'm just testing logical prove of concept. But seems great. I can each line "compare" to the regex and by that `/(#[\da-zA-Z]+){1}/s` sounds reasonable for what I want to achieve (to get always FIRST match).