# Delete multiple bracketed values ​in one sentence with regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one sentence.

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Neonatal(disseminated) listeriosis(P37.2) | 신생아(파종성) 리스테리아증(P37.2) |

i want this result

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Neonatal listeriosis | 신생아 리스테리아증 |

or

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Neonatal(disseminated) listeriosis | 신생아(파종성) 리스테리아증 |

I used the following regex

```
regex = "\(.*\)|\s-\s.*"
df['en'] = re.sub[regex,'',df['en')
df['ko'] = re.sub[regex,'',df['ko')
```

but result

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Neonatal | 신생아 |

My guess is that it recognizes the words before (and at the very end) the words disseminated and deletes them all.
I want to delete only the code(P37.2) at the end. Help

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual code you are running, given that regex usage and details can vary a LOT across different implementations. Especially given that this is likely to be related to the escaping of the parentheses

Comment: Use `*?` instead of `*` to make it _non-greedy_. [Here an example](https://regex101.com/r/Ub6Nr3/1).

Comment: I've add the code I actually used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)