# How do I make multiple regex search in a single string?

Tags: python, regex

New comer in stackoverflow community and python development here

I'm building an AI streamlit chatbot based on LLM and on Snowflake data
Typically the user requests informations on his own data, the AI that I prompt engineered will answer sql code in markdown so I can do a regex search in order to parse the bot answer and give the sql code to snowflake/snowpark so I can retrieve and display the query results. At this point everything is working and is going great

Now the issue comes. I want to make possible for the user to ask for graphs, plots, charts...So I created a list so that if one of the string in the list is in the prompt it gives the AI another system prompt. The prompt asks him to generate a python function (df in parameter) in markdown so that I can regex parse it and call it to display the plot. The AI generates everything perfectly, his code is correct and accurate but the parsing now doesn't work. The first parser take the first sql opening md tag all the way down to the python md closing tag and of I got a SQL compiling exception after

My code (regex in sql_match and graph_match):

````
if st.session_state.messages[-1]["role"] != "assistant":
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        response = ""
        resp_container = st.empty()
        for delta in openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=[{"role": m["role"], "content": m["content"]} for m in st.session_state.messages],
            stream=True,
            temperature=0
        ):
            response += delta.choices[0].delta.get("content", "")
            resp_container.markdown(response)

        message = {"role": "assistant", "content": response}
        sql_match = re.search(r"```sql(.*)```", response, re.DOTALL)
        if sql_match:
            sql = sql_match.group(1)
            conn = st.experimental_connection("snowpark")
            message["results"] = conn.query(sql)
            df = pd.DataFrame(message["results"])
            st.write(df)
            graph_match = re.search(r"```python\n(.*)\n```", response, re.DOTALL)
            print(graph_match)
            if graph_match:
                graph_match.group(1)
        st.session_state.messages.append(message)
````

Thanks a lot for your help!

I tried to use another LLM for the graph generation but it seems very complicated to mix both in this place
I tried to think of another way to parse it but I began python and programming 4 months ago I don't have much programming logic and knowledge yet...^^

Comment: It would really be clearer if you added an example of the output, what is currently captured by the first and second regex, and what you wanted to have instead, but my intuition tells me that it's simply that your regex capture is greedy (matches as much as it can) and you wanted it to be non-greedy: try with `r"```sql(.*?)```"` and `r"```python\n(.*?)\n```"` (with question marks) and tell me if it solves your issue (if yes this question is a simple duplicate even if it looks complicated on first read)

Comment: @Kaddath,
Thank for your answer and for your help. Making it non-greedy is indeed the solution
FI the output :
"Sure, I can help you with (...). Here is the SQL query (...) :

```sql
SELECT (...)
(...);
```

Now, let's move on to the Python part (...). Here is the Python function:
```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(...)
def graph(df):
(...)
return st.pyplot(fig)
```
This function (explanation...)"

I wanted r"```sql(.*)```" to get SELECT (...); and r"```python\n(.*)\n```" to get import (...) st.pyplot(df). But the first one was greedy and was taking it all.Thx!

Comment: Nice, I commented instead of redirecting to a duplicate right away because sometimes it's not enough, like if you have `)` in the sql, it could have stopped at the first found and give you a trucated result, and you would have needed another solution. I think the `\`\`\`` made it work, you don't find `)\`\`\`` usually in sql queries. Beware though that if it becomes the case one day, your result will stop there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

Comment: The link does answer to my question yes. I should have searched better ^^

Comment: No problem, it's harder to find a solution when you don't know how it is called ;)