# Regex to find header position getting all the text between first and last header

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that represents the text in a file, and I would like to find the header for the text. It is well structured, so I was gessing it would be fairly simple to do it, but the line breaks are breaking me (pun intentended)!
The header looks like this:

```
Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 2
```

And I can have one or many headers in the same string (pretty obvious, I know) where the only thing that changes is the page number.
My problem is that I can't find the whole header if I don't use the SingleLine modifier, and if I use it, it goes from the first header all the way to the last one, causing me to remove everything in between!

Here is an example text:

```
Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 1
Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Admodum accumsan disputationi eu sit. Vide electram sadipscing et per. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi.
Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis.
Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 2

More things
```

This makes my regex to match everything between the 1st `Start of the Header` to Pg. 2, making me miss all the funny Mussum Loren Ipsum in between!

I tried using some variations of `Start of the header.*Pg.*\d\n` with the SingleLine modifier.
I also tried without the SingleLine modifier, but then I can't find a way to match everything in between the `Start of the header` and the `Pg. 1`. I tried using different sequences of `.*\n*` and failed miserably!
Any tips on how to solve it?
I'm using Python 3.11 with `re.finditer` like this:
`headers = re.finditer("Start of the header.*Pg.*\d\n", self.text, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*?` or `(?s:.)*?`: [`Start of the header(?s:.)*?^Pg\.\s*\d\n`](https://regex101.com/r/av9njB/2).

Comment: Potential duplicates: *[How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159118)* and *[Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503413)*.

Comment: I looked at those two questions, but couldn't figure out how to apply the lazy quantifiers with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... it goes from the first header all the way to the last one, causing me to remove everything in between! ..."*

Use a *[lazy-quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching)*, `?`.

```
(?s)Start of the header.*?Pg.*?\d\n
```

Here is an example.

```py
for m in re.finditer('(?s)Start of the header.*?Pg.*?\d\n', s):
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 1

Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 2
```

Comment: I tried using the lazy-quantifier, but wasn't able to find a solution.
Your answer cleared that out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need a non-greedy expression to avoid consuming the whole input, but `.*?` does not include newlines, while `[\s\S]*?` does ( `\s` is a whitespace character, equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and `\S` is the negation of that).

```
import re

text = '''
Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 1
Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Admodum accumsan disputationi eu sit. Vide electram sadipscing et per. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi.
Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis.
Start of the header
Something inside the header
Random date
Pg. 2

More things
'''

headers = re.finditer(r"Start of the header[\s\S]*?Pg\.\s\d+", text)

for match in headers:
    print("{}\n".format(match.group(0)))
```

**CORRECTION**: I missed the fact that you used `re.DOTALL`; in that case, the dot would include the newline, so you just need the non-greedy quantifier. In that sense, the answer by @Reilas is more accurate.