A working RegEx match that begins at the first of two OR-words takes the unwanted last OR-word instead if I place more RegEx before it
For this String:
SELECT a, bc d AS Error FROM y WHERE 1=1 HAVING 1=1

I need to get two matching groups:

bc d as the code that builds the column called "Error". This is dummy code, do not care about the SQL.

Anything after one of the two words "WHERE" or "HAVING".


Check 1 (working)
(?<=WHERE|HAVING)(.*)


This works with a positive lookbehind, taken from How to match the first word after an expression with regex? - Stack Overflow. This is the second match that I need. It finds the first of two OR-words as the beginning of the match.
Check 2 (working)
Getting the last of the two OR-words as a match works as well, here with a positive lookahead since it is the other way round of Check 1:
(?>=SELECT\s+|,\s*)(.+)\s+AS\s+Error


Check 3 (the question)
If I put the two together with .* in the middle, this will only match after HAVING, but not after WHERE, though that is the first of the two searchwords and should be the beginning of the match - and as far as I understand it right, the positive lookbehind should take care of stopping the greedy .*. And it does, but only at the second word of the two OR-words.
(?>=SELECT\s+|,\s*)(.+)\s+AS\s+Error.*(?<=WHERE|HAVING)(.*)


How do I get the "Group 1" (as in Check 1 above) as in the Regex101 screenshot which already works, but also "Group 2" as I underlined red (as in Check 2 above) instead of this too late match?
For the checks, I took the default language and flavour of www.regex101.com, which is PCRE2 (PHP >=7.3) at the time of writing:


What language/tool/platform/framework/flavor are you using?

@InSync I have now put this at the end of the question.

Make your .* not greedy? https://regex101.com/r/86VUKs/1

https://regex101.com/r/KaEYmr/1

@Nick This works. I do not know that this makes something greedy not greedy.

Play with the link I gave you and remove the ? after .*, then look at the description on the RHS

@WiktorStribiżew Same with your answer, and you can even drop the lookbehind. Did not know :).

Yeah, you can also use a non-capturing group at the start, you do not need an atomic group - (?:=SELECT\s+|,\s*)(.+?)\s+AS\s+Error.*?((?:WHERE|HAVING).*)

@Nick Yes, I am aware of that help there, though I did not look it up. For just .*, it says: * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy). For .*?, it says: *? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy).

@WiktorStribiżew Yes, same trick again is what you mean, I guess. I make "(?>=SELECT\s+|,\s*)(.+)\s+AS\s+Error.*(?<=WHERE|HAVING)(.*)" lazy where the markers are, and then I do not need the lookarounds anymore.

So when you have WHERE and HAVING in your query string, .* will match to HAVING because it matches "as many times as possible", where .*? will match to WHERE because it matches "as few times as possible"

You both helped me, I am not sure how this should now be treated as to who and how to answer this. I am not a beginner of Regex, but I have forgotten about turning greedy to lazy and did not know that I can then replace the lookarounds. Though that might seem easy, it should be worth an answer.

No, "use lazy instead of greedy" is not worth the answer. The rest was already working for you.

@WiktorStribiżew I think it is. For me, even with quite some insight into RegEx, it is not easy since you also easily forget about such RegEx tricks again, I thought the lookbehind would dominate the greedy, and you may read from the remarks here that this was a good learning session that might help others as well.

The answers are https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503438/3832970 and 135 more here. No need to explain it for 136+th time.

@WiktorStribiżew The first link (=the link to this duplicate question) is right, but the 135 others do not always take up the whole story since I did not know that .* would grab everything it can get even if afterwards a lookbehind was set to grab the tail away again. It was a bit strange that only the second hit of that lookbehind would become the new match then. But yes, there are too many questions on this and that is also why I did not find an answer to this after browsing a lot of them.
